# Describing a signal using a mathematical formula

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm trying to develop an algorithm that based itself on a signal, the problem that I have: I should describe this signal using a mathematical expression. The signal looks like this:

[image]

I'm only interreset in the "big"  part like a Parabola.  my question is what are the method used to describe such functions or curves and how can I get error between the mathematical equation?

for example, here the interesting part is `-x² +1`, how can I get the equation and how can I get the difference between it the the signal that get?

Comment: This question is either way too broad, or off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: why ? I just need a hint on what I shouldbe looking for ?

Comment: On SO we don't give hints, we give answers to specific questions. This might work at http://math.stackexchange.com/ though it might be a bit broad there also. But I'll give one hint: Fourier

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: A Fourier transformation doesn't have the base set he wants (plain polynomials from what I can tell).

Comment: @BenjaminBannier True, but it gives "the mathematical equation" that approximates the signal. If there is a need for a polynomial, then it's a different thing.

Comment: "Best" fit would be a nth order polynomial with n-1 the number of points ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is a `sinc` function, or `sin(x)/x`. This is the fourier transform of a rectancular function. This is most probably the result of a fast fourier transform of a single harmonic component with a window which is way too short.

Given all this additional information you may estimate from the result you get:

- center frequency (the max in your result)
- width of main lobe
- distance of zeroes

From this information you can pretty easily reconstrunt all the parameters of your sinc function.

The `estimation error` is usually the RMS of the difference between model function and measured function.